# Spring MVC 5 program returning an error 404

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404

this is my first program with Spring MVC 5 and it's returning an error 404.
I am using Tomcat 7, Although I've tried tomcat 8 as well

[This is my directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7P2j.jpg)

I have used annotation based configuration, here are the components of my program

> Web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SpringMVCProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>webapp-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-web-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webapp-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app
```

> Spring configuration file::

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">
      <context:component-scan base-package="com.pgx.java.web" />
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
      </bean>
      <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
      <mvc:annotation-driven />
    </beans>
```

> MyController

```
    package com.pgx.java.web;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import com.pgx.java.bean.Person;
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping("/Hello")
    public String helloView(Model model) {

        Person p = new Person();
        p.setTitle("Dr.");
        p.setFirstName("John");
        p.setLastName("Watson");

        model.addAttribute("person", p);

        return "HelloWorld";
    }
}
```

> Person class

```
 package com.pgx.java.bean;
public class Person {

  private String title;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
}
```

> HelloWorld.jsp

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Hello World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Welcome ${person.title} ${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}!
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jsp file `HelloWorld.jsp` inside wrong place. It should be in `WEB-INF/view/jsp/` folder. Create a folder `view` inside `WEB-INF` and inside `view` folder put your  `HelloWorld.jsp`

Comment: I have tried your solution but I am still getting the same error. I am updating the question with new image of my directory structure.